# Selecting text file using file dialog and displaying filename

Tags: java

I'm a very inexperienced programmer, and the method below is trying to get the user to select a file from a folder and then display it.
The error I get when I try and run the code is

> filebox cannot be resolved

I commented out the `String filename = filebox.getFile();` and when run there are no errors and the directory opens, but without that line of code selecting a file does nothing as it is not then saved, please help.

```
public void readVehicleData()
{       
   FileDialog fileBox = new FileDialog(mainWindow,"Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
   fileBox.setVisible(true);
   fileBox.setDirectory(".");

   String filename = filebox.getFile();
   System.out.println(filename);
}
```

Comment: Try that; String filename = fileBox.getFile();  with uppercase B. There is no filebox, there is fileBox

Comment: This is a good question, but as @YusufK poined out, it's a simple typo, so voting to close. To the OP, I highly recommend that you pay very careful attention to the compiler errors you get in the future. While they can be cryptic and hard to understand at first glance, they are actually very informative once you get used to them.

Comment: Thanks everyone, very simple mistake on my part. Will help me in the future!

Answer (score 1):

```
  String filename = filebox.getFile();
```

This line should be

```
  String filename = fileBox.getFile();
```

As declared variable is `fileBox` not `filebox`. Java is `case-sensitive`

Comment: Or, in other words, Java is case-sensitive language.

Comment: absolutely, added the pt